# Does the work function of a metal change with respect to the wavelength of emitted photoelectrons?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I am taking an introduction course to quantum mechanics, in a homework question we are asked to calculate Planck's constant given the maximum energy and wavelengths of two types of photoelectron emissions from a metal.

We we're "warned" that we will not obtain the exact value of Planck's constant, and I want to identify why to better my answer. In my solution I formed two statements about the two types of emissions and equated them via the metal's work function

$$ E + \frac{hc}{\lambda} = W = \frac{hc}{\lambda} + E$$

I then solved for $h$. I did not receive an exact value, though it is very close. I would like to think that this is merely a result of using rounded numbers in the calculations. Though before I end the problem I would like to ensure that this is not a result of equating the value of the work function for each emission.

Thus, my question is, **does the work function of a metal change with respect to the energy/wavelength of an emitted photoelectron?**

Answer (score 1):

Equating the work functions is not the problem, the work function is a property of the surface of the material in question, and it is an expression of the energy it takes to remove an electron from this surface, independent of the energy of the incoming photon or of the energy of the outgoing electron. The work function is actually related to the atomic configuration of the irradiated surface, and although it may not be constant for different atomic configurations of the same material, it is always constant for the same surface.

Answer (score 0):

Work function is a property of metal, so it's completely independent of wavelength of incident photon n outgoing electron